# Proving not convexity of a set $S_{1}=\{ (x_{1},x_{2}):x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2=1 \}$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

$S_{1}=\{ (x_{1},x_{2}):x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2=1 \}$

I cant solve trying with an alpha value $\in[0,1]$ by two dummy vectors. Please can anyone tell me how to prove it is not convex set ?

what I tried is

Defined two vectors
$$a=(a_{1},a_{2})\in S_{1}$$ so $$a_{1}^2+a_{2}^2=1$$,
$$b=(b_{1},b_{2})\in S_{1}$$ so $$b_{1}^2+b_{2}^2=1$$,

and tried to prove
$$\alpha\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}\\a_{2}
\end{bmatrix}+(1-\alpha)\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}\\b_{2}
\end{bmatrix}\not\in S_{1} ? ?$$

it was so hard to me continuing this

Comment: Did you draw $S_1$? I mean this is pretty straightforward...

Comment: Hint: the points $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are in $S_1$. But what about the line segment which connects them?

Comment: Hint: if it were convex, then if you took any two points $p$ and $q$ in $S_1$, then the midpoint of $p$ and $q$ would also be $S_1$.

Comment: @User I must prove by equations

Comment: @SametSökel sure, I'm saying drawing it would make it easy for you to find a counterexample. See Mark's hint

Comment: @User my english is not that enough to understand what Mark said, and I just did that defined two vectors $a=(a_{1},a_{2})\in S_{1}$ so $a_{1}^2+a_{2}^2=1$,$b=(b_{1},b_{2})\in S_{1}$ so $b_{1}^2+b_{2}^2=1$, and tried to prove $\alpha\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}\\a_{2}
\end{bmatrix}+(1-\alpha)\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}\\b_{2}
\end{bmatrix}\not\in S_{1} ? ?$

Comment: @SametSökel I think you should edit your question to include more detailed attempts that you have made at solving the problem. Currently it is hard to help you, since it is not clear where you are stuck.

Comment: @supinf ok I did, thanks

Comment: Let's make sure we are on the same page. To prove that $S$ is convex, you need to prove that given any $a$ and $b$, we have for all $\alpha \in [0,1]$, $\alpha a + (1-\alpha) b \in S$. $\bf{But}$ to prove that $S$ is $\bf{not}$ convex, you need to prove that $\bf{there \ exist}$ $a,b \in S$ such that $\bf{for \ some}$ $\alpha \in [0,1]$, $\alpha a + (1-\alpha) b \not \in S$

Comment: @User yes ! we are definitely on the same page. When I continue with $(\alpha a_{1} +(1-\alpha)b_{1}) ^2+(\alpha a_{2} +(1-\alpha)b_{2}) ^2$, I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that a set $S$ is convex, you must prove that

"For all $x,y \in S$ and $\alpha \in [0,1]$, we have $\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y \in S$."

To show that a set $S$ is not convex, you need to prove the negation of the above statement, i.e.

"There exists $x,y \in S$ and $\alpha \in [0,1]$ such that $\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y \not\in S$."

In your particular problem, this means that you don't have to prove $\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y \not\in S$ for every choice of $x,y \in S$ and $\alpha \in [0,1]$, but rather just one particular choice.

So in your problem, pick any two distinct points in $S$ (say $x = (1,0)$ and $y = (-1,0)$) and some value of $\alpha \in [0,1]$ (say $\alpha = 1/2$), and see if you can check that $\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y \not\in S$ for this choice of $x$, $y$, and $\alpha$.

Comment: I cant explain how thankful I am, if the question was $S_{1}=\{ (x_{1},x_{2}):x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2<=1 \}$ and asked proving **convexity** how would the solution be ?